# Determine the base b in

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have doubts about how to solve this issue about bases in numbering systems:

"Determine the base b in $(104)_b = 8285$"

can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to write $(104)_b$ as a polynomial in $b$?

Comment: When you are done with this exercise you could try to find in which basis $6 + \sqrt{64} = 10$ is valid.

Comment: Also note that $90^2=8100$. This is not far away form $8281\ (=8285-4)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: In the number $104_b$, the final digit represents the units, the middle digit represents the number of "$b$"s, and the leftmost digit represents the number of "$b^2$"s. (Compare to base $10$, where these would be units, tens, and hundreds.) In other words, you have
$$b^2+4 = 8285.$$

Now solve for $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(104)_b = 1\cdot b^2 + 0 \cdot b + 4$ you get the equation
$$b^2+4 = 8285,$$
which you should be able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The number in base $10$ is $8285$. Remember that this means the number can be expressed as
$$5\cdot 10^0 + 8\cdot 10^1 + 2\cdot 10^2 + 8\cdot 10^3 = 8285$$
You are told that, in base $b$, the number can be expressed as
$$4\cdot b^0 + 0\cdot b^1 + 1\cdot b^2 = 8285$$
The left side is just $b^2 + 4$. So you want to solve
$b^2 + 4 = 8285$ for $b$.